# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format' python string

Tags: python, string

I wrote a program in python to find compound interest (more like copied). This program was written in python 2 and I am having a problem on the last line `.format(years)`.

I need to know what I can do with this code, and how to write it properly in Python 3. Also with the `{}` part in the last line. Should I change it to `%s`? The error says:

> "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'".

My code looks like this :

```py
# Estimated yearly interest

print ("How many years will you be saving ? ")
years = int(input("Enter the number of years : "))

print("How much money is currently in your account ? ")
principal = float(input("Enter current amount in account : "))

print("How much money do you plan on investing monthly ? ")
monthly_invest = float(input("Monthly invest : "))

print("What do you estimate the interest of this yearly investment would be ? ")
interest = (float(input("Enter the interest in decimal numbers (10% = 0.1) : ")))

print(' ')

monthly_invest = monthly_invest * 12
final_amount = 0

for i in range(0, years ):
    if final_amount == 0:
        final_amount = principal
    final_amount = (final_amount + monthly_invest) * (1 + interest)

print("This is how much money you will have after {} years:  ").format(years) + str(final_amount)
```

Comment: The parentheses should be at the end instead of after the string literal. Also, using the mathematical formula would be easier

Comment: I imagine if you looked at the Python documentation you would find that it is a perfectly acceptable method to format a string. - https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it a bit of a shame that no one recommended [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). There are only available since Python 3.6 but they are quite powerful, easy to use and the recommended string formatting option in [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#specification) (unless I'm mistaken).

If you want to get serious about python and work with other people I really recommend reading up on best practices, in this case, f-strings.

Solution using f-strings:

`print(f"This is how much money you will have after {years} years:  {final_amount}")`

Comment: I am a beginner and i am still learning the basics, but thank you for your opinion. This works too.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```py
print("This is how much money you will have after {} years:  ").format(years) + str(final_amount)
```

to

```py
print("This is how much money you will have after {} years:  ".format(years)) + str(final_amount)
```

`format()` is a method of the `string` class. You're using it on the `print()` function which is of `NoneType`, hence the error.

Comment: It works when i put the close parenthesis on the last.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a normal string concatenation like this :

`Print("This is how much money you will have after " + format(years) + " years: " +str(final_amount)`

Or if you wish to keep the same format you can do this

`print("This is how much money you will have after {} years:  ".format(years) + str(final_amount))`

Answer (score 1):

A very basic solution would be to change the last line to:

```
print("This is how much money you will have after {} years:".format(years), str(round(final_amount,2)))
```

That will do the trick for you

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Numpy's financial functions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.financial.html)

For $1000 invested monthly for 10 years at annual rate of 4%:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.fv(.04/12, 10*12, -1000, 0)
147249.8047254786
```

With an initial principal of $100,000:

```
>>> np.fv(.04/12, 10*12, -1000, -100000)
296333.07296730485
```